# Select Box With Li Elements from Another Select Box

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu

Okay, I know that my title is not very informative. Let me explain.

There is a page I am trying to do over with jQuery.  On their page (the old page), there is a select dropdown menu that I am bringing over to my (new) page.  Their select dropdown is using a ul with li elements, while mine is using select with option elements.

Here is what I have:

```
var totalQuestions = jQuery('.rcbItem').length; //get the total elements in theirs

for ( x = 0; x < totalQuestions; x++) //for loop to create the dropdown on mine
{
    var questionText = jQuery('.rcbItem:eq(' + x + ')').html();

    jQuery('#selectQuestion').append(jQuery(document.createElement('option')).attr(
    {
        'value' : "Question" + x
    }).html(questionText));
}

var strQuestion = jQuery('#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ddlQuestion_Input').val();  //gets the value currently in THEIR select field

var objQuestionNext = jQuery("#selectQuestion").find("option:contains('" + strQuestion + "')");

objQuestionNext.attr(
{
    selected : 'true'
});  //finds the question in MY list that matches THEIR select field, and then selects that one
```

This is the code that runs every time I select a question from my dropdown list:

```
jQuery('#selectQuestion').change(function()
{
    strQuestion = jQuery('#selectQuestion :selected').val(); //get the value of "option", which is Question + x
    strAnswer = jQuery('#txtQuestionAnswer').val();

    intQuestionNumber = strQuestion.substr(8, 2).trim(); //gets the number (so Question + x becomes x)

    jQuery('#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ddlQuestion_Arrow')[0].click(); //I click THEIR dropdown menu

    jQuery('.rcbItem:eq(' + (intQuestionNumber-1) + ')').click();  //Select THEIR li element that matches MINE)

    jQuery('#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ctbAnswer').val(strAnswer);
});
```

This works 90% of the time.

However, if I choose the very last option in my list, this is what happens.  It selects it, which is fine, but if I then choose another question from the list, it starts selecting the one directly above the one that I want, and continues to do that until I completely reload the page.  This ONLY happens if I choose the very last element in my dropdown.

I have been racking my brain about this and have not found an answer.  Can anyone offer some insight?  Thanks.

EDIT: I finally found the problem.  In their code, the .rcbItem class that every one of their li elements had was being overwritten by a .rcbHover class when the click happened.  So to fix it, I basically changed .rcbItem to `jQuery('.rcbList li')....` and it works perfectly now.

Thank you for your help guys.

Comment: Have you tried debugging it to see where it's going wrong?  Could you create a demo on http://www.jsfiddle.net?

Comment: At least showing us some HTML markup would helpful.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have any HTML to give you.  The only thing I've touched on the page is the Javascript.  Their stuff is heavily coded in ASP, not HTML, and I cannot touch any of that because it's their code.

Comment: Odd that you were able to get all these class and variable names without any HTML...?

Comment: @snowfi6916 Open your browser and go to "view source".  If the elements are created dynamically, every modern browser still has some way of retrieving the HTML.

Comment: @kmd97 I can get the ids that they use.  I cannot change their markup though, which is why I'm trying to just take my stuff and put it in their stuff and vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that this one is OK?

```
jQuery('#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ddlQuestion_Arrow')[0].click();
```

You trigger jQuery's `.click` not on jQuery but on DOM element

Comment: That particular ID belongs to an "a" element, so I'm pretty sure that's okay.